# função a partir de onclick em iframe de url externa

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Como receber os parametros de um onclick estando o link em um iframe de url externa?
no mesmo servidor faz exatamente o que preciso, ja funcionando com a ajuda de um usuario do Stack (dvd).

**função esta assim:**

```
         function funcao1(dom,seg,par){
        var converter = atob(par); // decodifica base64
        var decodif_url = decodeURIComponent(converter); // decodifica uri
        var parx = JSON.parse(decodif_url); 
        var parx = parx.nome; 
        var parx = btoa(parx); // recolocar apenas nome em base64 para URL
        var url_ = "http://www."+dom.toLowerCase()+".com/pesquisa.php?"+parx+"&segmento="+par;
        window.open(url_,"_blank"); // abre em nova guia
        }
```

**link no iframe url EXTERNA esta assim:**

```
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:parent.funcao1('TESTE','ABCD', 'JTdCJTIybm9tZSUyMiUzQSUyMmpvYW8lMjIlMkMlMjJpZGFkZSUyMiUzQSUyMjM3JTIyJTdE');">
                          <nobr>TESTE</nobr>
                       </a>
```

Comment: Vc fez o teste? Não funcionou?

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, essa nova pergunta foi para saber se há como contornar a restrição de acesso para executar este javascript em iframes com url de outro domínio (url externa).

Comment: Ah tah rs   çuçeçu!

Comment: Neste caso se for um servidor externo, vc teria que incluir a função lá e setar alguma coisa que permita CORS.